# Best way to structure MongoDB with the following use cases?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database

sorry to have to ask this but I am new to MongoDB (only have experience with relational databases) and was just curious as to how you would structure your MongoDB.

The documents will be in the format of JSONs with some of the following fields:

```
{
    "url": "http://....",
    "text": "entire ad content including HTML (very long)",
    "body": "text (50-200 characters)",
    "date": "01/01/1990",
    "phone": "8001112222",
    "posting_title": "buy now"
}
```

Some of the values will be very long strings.

Each document is essentially an ad from a certain city. We are storing all ads for a lot of big cities in the US (about 422). We are storing more ads every day, and the amount of ads per city varies from as little as 0 to as big as 2000. The average is probably around 700-900.

We need to do the following types of queries, in almost instant time (if possible):

- Get all ads for any specific city, for any specific date range.
- Get all ads that were posted by a specific phone number, for any city, for any date range.

What would you recommend? I'm thinking I should have 422 collections - one for each city. I'm just worried about the query time when we query for phone numbers because it needs to go through each collection. I have an iterable list of all collection names.

Or would it be faster to just have one collection so that I don't have to switch through 422 collections?

Thank you so much, everyone. I'm here to answer any questions!

EDIT:

Here is my "iterating through all collections" snippet:

```
for name in glob.glob("Data\Nov. 12 - 5pm\*"):
    val = name.split("5pm")[1].split(".json")[0][1:]
    coll = db[val]

    # Add into collection here...
```

Comment: For starters you should convert to using [BSON Dates](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/bson-types/#date) rather than the "strings" you presently have. For one, the strings are not even in lexical format and therefore it would not be possible for you to select a range in any way. As for your collection choice it depends on how you intend to use the data. If data is only required to be searched within it's own domain then you can seperate to collections. If you intend to search across domains then this is counterintuitive, and sharding should rather be the goal.

Comment: What do you mean by "within it's own domain?" For the data, we will be returning it in .JSON format by appending it to a list of JSONs. Our goal is to retrieve, for example, all ads by a certain phone number. We want to retrieve the entire list of them with each one's data. From there, we will display it in a user-friendly fashion.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not offer any operations which get results from more than one collection, so putting your data in multiple collections is not advisable in this case.

You can considerably speed up all the use-cases you mentioned by creating [indexes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-index/) for them. When you have a very large dataset and always query for exact equality, then [hashed indexes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-hashed-index/) are the fastest.

When you query a range of dates (between day x and day y), you should use [the Date type](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Date/) and not strings, because this not just allows you to use lots of handy [date operators in aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) but also allows you to speed up ranged queries and sorts with ascending or descending indexes.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the response! I'll look thoroughly into indexes and hashed indexes. For the multiple collections issue, is working around by iterating (re-instantating) each collection too slow? Right now, I have some code written to iterate through each of the 422 collections. I've edited my main body with the it.

Comment: @Matt That depends. How slow is "too slow" for your use-case? Calling `collection = db.collectionName` is negligible because it happens completely client-sided. What you should be worried about is hammering the database with 422 queries when one with a proper index would do the same thing much faster. I hope you are at least making them asynchronously and don't wait for the database response before sending the next one.

Comment: I do plan on making the happen asynchronously - that was just the rudimentary fashion of how I was planning on doing it. I want to be able to get nearly immediate results when we search for all ads of a given phone number. Nearly immediate means within 1-2 seconds. Just wondering, though, how exactly does indexing increase performance? Is it faster to compare `"_id"`'s then it is to compare `document['phone']'s`?

Comment: @Matt searching without an index means the equivalent to a "full table scan" in SQL: the database looks at every single document in the database, which means the runtime is O(n). An index is a binary tree, so searching is a O(log n) operation. The _id field always has an index on it by default.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't making "city" a field in your JSON solve your problem? That way you only need to do something like this `db.posts.find({ city: {$in: ['Boston', 'Michigan']}})`

Comment: Yeah I actually just did that. It helps, however the query time is taking forever when I run `collection.find()`

Comment: Try adding indexes on the fields you queried on. It should help speed up the query time.

Comment: Ok, will do. I'm getting some odd errors when I try to add the index, though. It reads, `TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'createIndex' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.` My code is `     coll.createIndex( { phone: 1 } ) coll.createIndex( { city: 1 } )` Any idea? Also, if I'm going to be searching by phone and then filtering those by date, should I still only have phone as the index?

Comment: What version of mongodb are you using? Sounds like you have version 2.x installed.  
  
2.x uses `db.records.ensureIndex( { userid: 1 } )`  
3.x uses `db.records.createIndex( { userid: 1 } )`.
  
You may as well index the date field, and add dates conditions in your queries.

Comment: I just tried ensureIndex, as well, and I got the same error. If I don't have quotes around the userid tag in the middle, then it tells me `NameError: name 'userid' is not defined`

Comment: I assume you're running those queries on MongoDB shell? What is the name of your database and collection? Assuming you're running this on mongodb shell and your database name is `database_name` and the name of the collection is `collection_name` then you should run `use database_name` then followed by either `db.collection_name.ensureIndex({ phone: 1})`

Comment: It's actually within my Python code - not in the shell. I'm calling the function with a collection object.